# Two Slow DSL or One Fast DSL?

Tags: networking, internet, home-networking, internet-connection, dsl

I'm planning to do a lot of video conference chat, unfortunately, at 2Mbps, there are times I experience loss of sound during chat and even without using the internet, there are times that the connection drops and sometimes this happens a lot during peak hours of the day which means I have to restart my modem constantly during those times.

I'm not sure what's the best decision to alleviate this problem. So far my options are:
1) Upgrading to a faster connection (6Mbps) and hope for the best
2) Load balance by subscribing a business DSL (2mbps) from the same company(it's cheaper than the 3rd)
3) Load balance by subscribing to another company(2mbps) (this company has a bandwidth limit and will bring your speed down to 256kbps once it's exceeded)

Comment: Open a command prompt and do a " ping google.com -t " Let that run for about an hour or more. press ctrl+c and if your ping lost is more than 2-3% that by itself can create a great deal of lag time. 2Mbps is slow but the lost packets when you ping are making the connection drag. A faster connection would make those pings more forgiving tho.

Comment: I did, last week it was minimal, but today, I had ping lost 20% of the time

Comment: reworded my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the 20% packet loss. Contact your internet service provider and advise them of the problem you are having. A faster connection may help a little bit but try reading something with 20% of the words missing....

Comment: They won't do anything about it. Sometimes that connection drop gets worse if I contact them. Another thing I'm worried about is the connection drops, will this be fixed if I upgrade to a faster connection?

Comment: If they do not want to provide customer service, then you don't have to continue being a customer. Also, if you live in the United States you can report them https://www.fcc.gov/help/how-do-i-file-complaint-against-my-internet-service-provider